# String (sentence) to Array and output Array in one sentence and put the last letter of every word to the beginning of every individual word

Tags: java, arrays, bukkit, spigot

I have a question regarding

I want to output following:
When the Player types Hello, the output should be oHell.
When the Player types Hello World, the output should be oHello dWorl.

```
public class ConnectionListener implements Listener {

ArrayList<String> newArrOfStr = new ArrayList<String>();
@EventHandler
public void onMessageSent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {

    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    String output = event.getMessage();
    event.setCancelled(true);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(output);
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    String[] arrOfStr = output.split(" ");


    int i = 0;
    for (String a : arrOfStr)
        newArrOfStr.add(a);

    player.sendMessage(newArrOfStr(beginning - end));

    newArrOfStr.clear();
```

```
Hello >> oHell
Hello World >> oHell dWorl
A BC AAR >> A CB RAA
```

I just dont understand how to output an Array to a nondefined ending, beacause the Player could send multiple arguments and not only 1, 2 or 3.

The "beginning -end" is the space I mean. I have the complete Array under the tag "newArrOfStr" and now would like to output the single words with a Space inbetween. It is supposed to be one sentence and should **not** be output like this:

A
BC
RAA

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jekyi.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what your exact question is? Is the problem that you don't know how to send the message to the player? What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to output an array in the chat without the brackets and commas.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to make this so complicated. Regex is your friend! Here's all you need:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onMessageSent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
    event.setMessage(event.getMessage().replaceAll("(\w)\B(\w+)", "$2$1"));
}
```

Regex explanation:

- **Group 1** `(\w)`: Any word character. This is the first character of each word. Surrounded by parenthesis to make it be a replacement group.
- `\B`: Any non-word boundary. Basically this means "stop matching this string group when you hit a word boundary.
- **Group 2**: `(\w+)`: That `\w` is the same as above. `+` means match one or more. Parenthesis again to group them
- `$2$1` - `$2` means the second group, `$1` means the first group.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the solution to your problem: The way to approach this is by declaring a `String result` and then using a for loop to build the String:

```java
String result = "";
for (String s : newArrOfStr) {
  result = result + s + " ";
}
player.sendMessage(result);
```

I don't think your Function does what you want it to do, and there is a lot of unused things or other things that are a little bit more complicated than they should be.

- I don't think you need the ArrayList `newArrOfStr` at all, if all you want to do is send the message to the player. Instead of looping over the ArrayList `newArrOfStr`, you can simply just loop over your `arrOfStr`:

  `for (String s : arrOfStr) {`
- If for some other reason you do think you need the ArrayList, instead of adding all the elements with the for loop you have right now, change it to this:

```java
//Bad:
for (String a : arrOfStr)
  newArrOfStr.add(a);
//Good:
newArrOfStr.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrOfStr));
```

- Then, you have the unused variable `int i = 0`. Consider removing it.
- The StringBuilder you created is also not used.

I tried to write your function in a way that I think it will work:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onMessageSent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
  event.setCancelled(true);
  Player player = event.getPlayer();
  String output = event.getMessage();
  String[] wordsInOutput = output.split(" ");
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < wordsInOutput.length; i++) {
    String word = wordsInOutput[i];
    String newWord = word.charAt(word.length() - 1) + word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
    result = result + newWord + " ";
  }

  player.sendMessage(result);
}
```

This is the way everyone can understand it, but of course IntelliJ Idea has some suggestions so lets apply those:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onMessageSent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
  event.setCancelled(true);
  Player player = event.getPlayer();
  String output = event.getMessage();
  String[] wordsInOutput = output.split(" ");
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (String word : wordsInOutput) {
    String newWord = word.charAt(word.length() - 1) + word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
    result.append(newWord).append(" ");
  }

  player.sendMessage(result.toString());
}
```

Now this is a working function. I hope this helps.